# Jquery Modal window that allows Jquery

Tags: jquery, window, modal-dialog

I need a modal window, that allows content to be added inside this window. This content is ANOTHER jquery script.

To give you a better idea, I need a content modal window to load, inside this window have a jquery gallery with different images.

Any out there?

Answer (score 0):

I use jQuery UI dialog http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

If you want to load another html page inside it, use it like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dialog").load('content_url.html').dialog();
});
```

You can have whatever you like in that content_url.html, including other jQuery scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Reveal is a nice modal plugin for jQuery: http://www.zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin

It hijacks a hidden div inside your page, so you could potentially do anything to that div and have it appear inside the modal.